# List all files with two letter extension

Tags: windows, command-line

How can I list all files with two letter extension using windows command line.

I tried `dir *.??` but it displays also all folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude folders use the `/A` parameter:

```
dir /A-D *.??
```

Enter `dir /?` to get a full list or all parameters

Answer (score 2):

Read  [Wildcards](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html): *`?` Matches any 0 or 1 character, except for {dot}*.

`dir /A-D *.??` displays files with all 2-characters, 1-character and 0-character extension.

I'd [redirect (pipe)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) the `dir` output to [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

`dir /B /A:-D | findstr "\...$"` to list all files with *two* **character** extension

`dir /B /A:-D | findstr /I /R "\.[a-z][a-z]$"` to list all files with *two* **letter** extension:

Here

- `.`  = any single character,
- `\.` = the dot character literally,
- `[a-z]` = any characters within the specified range (letters between `a` and `z`),
- `$` = line position: end of line,
- `/I` = case-insensitive search.